# error: cannot access AbstractSafeParcelable class file for com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.AbstractSafeParcelable not found

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-cloud-messaging

error: cannot access AbstractSafeParcelable
class file for com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.AbstractSafeParcelable not found

Comment: Do you seriously expect people to be able to help you with a "question" like this?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41408514/com-google-android-gms-common-internal-safe-parcel-safe-parcelable-not-found

Comment: @PatrickHund I think he is implying this: "I have not idea what is going on with this?" Any hints/help please? I know it looks lazy for someone to ask without showing evidence of having done his own research first, but I will not blame him immediately. Sometimes I have felt totally lost and asked a question to see if it is on top of someone's mind the solution, and then I work hard to figure things out myself if it is not on top of someone's mind an easy solution. But I know, the question does not reveal any evidence of research and it looks lazy but still, it has 5,235 views right now.

Answer (score 6):

it resloved by changing to 10.0.1 from 9.0.0-  in  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'