# Cordova GooglePlus plugin crashes build for android

Tags: android, cordova, google-plus

I am using the `cordova-plugin-googleplus` for sign in with Google, and when trying to build I get:

```
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
D:\..\project\platforms\android\src\nl\xservices\plugins\GooglePlus.java:151: error: cannot access AbstractSafeParcelable
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso.build());
            ^
  class file for com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.AbstractSafeParcelable not found
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

I looked everywhere, and no solution worked for me.

Plugin version: 5.1.1

Cordova version: 7.0.1

I am already using `compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1"` so the other issue thread is not a duplicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41408514/com-google-android-gms-common-internal-safe-parcel-safe-parcelable-not-found

Comment: Possible duplicate of [com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safe parcel.safe parcelable not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41408514/com-google-android-gms-common-internal-safe-parcel-safe-parcelable-not-found)

Comment: Thanks @Eric I am aware of that one, the solution there was not helpful, I am using `compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1"` already